# YQL Fantasy Sports: Get a list of league_ids based on game_key

Tags: yql, yahoo-api

Here's the thing:

I want do to something quite simple:

- Select Season
- Get games for that season
- Select Game
- Get leagues for that game that season
- Select league
- Get Teams for that league
- Select Team
- Get Players for that team

This falls apart at the 'Get leagues' step.

**I cannot get leagues based on a game_key.
I can only get 'my' leagues as a user, not all leagues though.**

To get any league I have to have a league_id, which I don't have since I can't query the table without one! I hope you understand my predicament.

Is that even possible? 
Or is there a hardcoded list of league_ids somewhere?

Another thing I tried was this:
- Select Season
- Get games for that season
- Select Game
- Get players for that game that season

The problem with that is the limit of 25 players. I guess I would be happy with that solution as well if I could get all of them.

**How can I get the league ID, then find the team and then the players? Any ideas?**

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly! I don't have a way to get the information.
I want to make the table list all available league_ids, but I cannot do that.

Comment: Could you share the YQL for each step.  For example, step 1, to get the season resource key you have to run the following query.  The resource key is the first number in the league_key below, i.e., 371 is the league key for NFL 2017
 select * from fantasysports.games where game_key='nfl';

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Fantasy Football Api does not return any league_id information from any of their endpoints.  For whatever reason this is still a manual process and you must log into your username, navigate to the league and extract the league_id to include in the league url on a request.